# Custom LaTeX chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Be default chapters look like:

```
Chapter 1

Chapter name.
```

How can I make chapters in LaTeX look something like this?

```
Chapter 1. Chapter Name.
```

That is: add a dot after chapter number, and place the chapter name straight after the chapter number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]